# issues using preg_match to get data from xml file

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use an external site's API to get users IP info (country, city, etc etc) with `file_get_contents`:

```
$ht="http://api.hostip.info/?ip=99.99.99.99";//example ip address<<
$com = file_get_contents("$ht");

preg_match('/<countryName>(.*)<\/countryName>/',$com,$oun);
preg_match('/<gml:name>(.*)<\/gml:name>/',$com,$it);
$country=$oun[1];
$city=$it[1];
echo $country, $city;
```

I can get the country, IP and other things with that code, just not the city...

I think the issue lies with the
**:**

in `gml:name`....

Here is the XML I'm trying to get the data from:

http://api.hostip.info/

Comment: How about using a proper XML parser instead of regular expressions?

Comment: Why don't you use [`simplexml`](http://php.net/simplexml) for reading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the colon `'/<gml\:name>(.*)<\/gml\:name>/'`

Comment: I did a run in cli and that worked for me. PHP version 5.3.3.7, `preg_match('/<gml\:name>(.*)<\/gml\:name>/', '<gml:name>hostip</gml:name>', $res);`